# What is event sourcing and how can I implement it in Java?

Tags: java, logging, file-io

I have heard about the term *event sourcing* but I am confused about the difference between an *event sourcing framework* and a *logging library* such as Log4J. Can anyone clarify, provide a source code example and point me to the right direction in learning more about this programming topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a logging framework such as Log4J has to deal with log levels, such as Debug, Trace, Error, etc. Event sourcing is more targeted to *message or event persistency* in disk. The idea is to save messages as fast as you can to disk, without adding latency to your application, so you can have a journal of everything that happened in your system for later replay or auditing. Because of the low-latency requirements, most event sourcing libraries will be asynchronous, in other words, the actual file i/o will be performed by a separate thread in parallel with the thread doing the logging. The fastest way to do this *pipelining* among threads is to use the disruptor pattern.

Below is an example using [CoralLog](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/07/getting-started-with-corallog-for-event-sourcing/), a level logging and event sourcing framework, of which I am one of the developers:

```
Logger myLogger = Log.createLogger("/home/coralblocks/logs/", "myLogFile.log");

myLogger.log(byteArray);
myLogger.log(stringBuilder);
myLogger.log(byteBuffer);
myLogger.log("This is a message!", "a=", a, "b=", b);
// log as much as you want...

// you can also do:
myLogger.drainAndWait(); // blocking call

// and when you are done:

myLogger.close(); // non-blocking call

// or:
myLogger.drainCloseAndWait(); // blocking call
```

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralLog

Comment: This answer is a good example of an answer, because it includes more than just the sales pitch for your tool/library, but an example of how to use it to solve the specific problem in the question.